# Numpy creating an array of powers of 2

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I tried :

```
>>>a = np.array(2**np.arange(42)[::-1],dtype = np.uint64)
```

and got

```
>>> a
array([                   0,                    0,                    0,
                          0,                    0,                    0,
                          0,                    0,                    0,
                          0, 18446744071562067968,           1073741824,
                  536870912,            268435456,            134217728,
                   67108864,             33554432,             16777216,
                    8388608,              4194304,              2097152,
                    1048576,               524288,               262144,
                     131072,                65536,                32768,
                      16384,                 8192,                 4096,
                       2048,                 1024,                  512,
                        256,                  128,                   64,
                         32,                   16,                    8,
                          4,                    2,                    1], dtype=uint64)
```

`18446744071562067968` is certainly not `2 to the power 31` and after that the answers are certainly not zero!
to check for some kind of overflow error I tried :

```
>>> a[0] = 2**42
```

and got:

```
>>> a
array([       4398046511104, ..... 

  the rest the same
```

Can anybody tell me what has gone wrong?

Comment: You're doing the computations in the wrong dtype and casting too late. Same reason `float(1/2)` is `0.0` in Python 2 and `decimal.Decimal(1.0/10.0)` isn't `decimal.Decimal('0.1')`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `np.arange(42)` is defaulting to a *signed integer*, likely `np.int32`, probably because you are on a 32-bit architecture or you are on Windows. Ditch the `np.array` wrapper, which is totally useless, and pass the dtype to `np.arange`:

```
2**np.arange(42, dtype = np.uint64)[::-1]
```